# Canvas.drawRect() not drawing anything

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

My painter in my Canvas class isn't drawing rectangles, despite me configuring it to do so.

I have a simple Canvas Layout and I've set up 6 rectangle painters that should draw a grey rectangle based if a corresponding boolean flag is true. Despite this, for some reason no rectangle is drawn even when a given boolean is true.

As seen in the screenshot below (taken from within the scope of onDraw), any given rectangle has valid coordinates during runtime so it should be visible. Before you ask; yes i've verified that the canvas.drawRect() calls in my code are reached. They simply don't draw anything.
[image]

What am I missing?

Below is my Canvas class. Did I mess up somewhere?

```
public class Canvas_StrumPad extends View {

private Paint eStringRectPainter, aStringRectPainter, dStringRectPainter, gStringRectPainter,
        bStringRectPainter, eeStringRectPainter;
private int viewWidth, viewHeight, stringRectWidth;
public int eRectBoundary, aRectBoundary, dRectBoundary, gRectBoundary, bRectBoundary, eeRectBoundary;

public boolean eStringTouched = true, aStringTouched, dStringTouched = true, gStringTouched, bStringTouched,
        eeStringTouched = true;

public Canvas_StrumPad(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

public Canvas_StrumPad(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

public Canvas_StrumPad(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView();
}

private void initView(){
    eStringRectPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    eStringRectPainter.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    eStringRectPainter.setAlpha(128);

    aStringRectPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    aStringRectPainter.setColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
    aStringRectPainter.setAlpha(128);

    dStringRectPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    dStringRectPainter.setColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
    dStringRectPainter.setAlpha(128);

    gStringRectPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    gStringRectPainter.setColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
    gStringRectPainter.setAlpha(128);

    bStringRectPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bStringRectPainter.setColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
    bStringRectPainter.setAlpha(128);

    eeStringRectPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    eeStringRectPainter.setColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
    eeStringRectPainter.setAlpha(128);
}

public void setViewParams(int width, int height){
    viewWidth = width;
    viewHeight = height;

    stringRectWidth = viewWidth/6;

    eRectBoundary = stringRectWidth;
    aRectBoundary = stringRectWidth*2;
    dRectBoundary = stringRectWidth*3;
    gRectBoundary = stringRectWidth*4;
    bRectBoundary = stringRectWidth*5;
    eeRectBoundary = stringRectWidth*6;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (eStringTouched){
        canvas.drawRect(0,viewHeight,eRectBoundary,0,eStringRectPainter);
    }
    if (aStringTouched){
        canvas.drawRect(eRectBoundary,viewHeight,aRectBoundary,0,aStringRectPainter);
    }
    if (dStringTouched){
        canvas.drawRect(aRectBoundary,viewHeight,dRectBoundary,0,dStringRectPainter);
    }
    if (gStringTouched){
        canvas.drawRect(dRectBoundary,viewHeight,gRectBoundary,0,gStringRectPainter);
    }
    if (bStringTouched){
        canvas.drawRect(gRectBoundary,viewHeight,bRectBoundary,0,bStringRectPainter);
    }
    if (eeStringTouched){
        canvas.drawRect(bRectBoundary,viewHeight,viewWidth,0,eeStringRectPainter);
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

}

Comment: why always `0` as `bottom` parameter in `drawRect` method call?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I forgot that Android Y coordinates increase as you move down the screen (top to bottom, towards the home button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting bottom as 0 should be the problem. I tried your code with following rect sides and its working:

```
if (eStringTouched) {
  canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, eStringRectPainter);
}
```

Set a positive value greater than top for bottom, and similarly positive value greater than left for right.